# How to deploy war file on production without hurting existing users

Tags: java, apache, iis, jboss, tomcat7

I am generating a war file and want to replace with the current war file in the production.
What are the standards followed to do it in Apache or any other standard server?
How do people check current logged-in user on the website, choosing a good time to replace, Is it possible to do it without shutting down the server?
IIS is intelligent enough to keep the current user on the old file and redirect newly logged-in user to the new production code. Can we do it some what similar in JBoss or Apache?
Thanks

Comment: Hot Deploy is the term, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

JBOSS has a hotdeploy directory, which allows you to deploy a new version of a WAR quickly. Under the hood it keeps the old WAR as well as the old metadata in the permgen space so currently executing requests aren't interrupted by this operation. The only problem is that this can up the amount of Permgen you require and can grow over time under certain conditions until an out of permgen space error occurs.